# Python code different when run in python.exe

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import win32api
import wmi

def username_func():
    uname = win32api.GetUserName()
    print "Username is:" ,uname, "\r "

def disk_func():
    c = wmi.WMI()
    for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk (DriveType=3):
            print disk.Caption, "%0.1f%% vrij \r" % (100.0 * long (disk.FreeSpace) / long     (disk.Size)),long (disk.FreeSpace) / long (1073741824),"gb van",long (disk.Size) / long     (1073741824),"gb"
            print

def main():
    username_func()
    disk_func()

main()

raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

when i run this is pyscripter it gives me this output:

```
Username is: ****** 

C: 66.7% vrij 
79 gb van 119 gb

D: 21.9% vrij 
130 gb van 596 gb
```

when i double click the python.py i get a different output:

```
sername is: *****
79 gb van 119 gb

130 gb van 596 gb
```

why is this? am i forgetting something?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to formatting your code correctly, you should change your `\r` to `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code in a main() function and then write:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I remember I read in python api that it's important on Windows. But I don't remember why. If I find the link I'll post it later.

Comment: It's just a convention really, and no more or less important on Windows than any other platform. The reason why it is good is that it means you can run your code as a script but you can also import it as a module and re-use functions such as `username_func` and `disk_func` in other bits of code.